# How to get a smooth gradient value from red to white from a value of 0 to 1?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3

How would I generate a value of red to white when using a scale of 0 to 1?

I have a list of values from 0 to 1 and if the value is 0 I want to show full red and if the value is 1 I want to show full white.

I'm sure there are API to find this value but I'm drawing a blank on it.

Here is what I have so far:

```
var color:Number = value==0 ? 0xFF0000 : 0xFFFFFF;
```

This obviously does not support gradient values.

Code for JavaScript would also help solve this.

Comment: You can use my class, it allows to manipulate color channels: https://bitbucket.org/thydmitry/ru.delimiter/src/default/classes/ru/delimiter/math/RGB.as

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the API. It's in ColorUtils.adjustBrightness();

If I pass the RGB value and the brightness value * 256 it like it's returning the adjust color. If the color I wanted to adjust was not white I do not believe this function would work.

```
var color:Number = adjustBrightness(0xFF0000, brightness*256);

public static function adjustBrightness(rgb:uint, brite:Number):uint
{
    var r:Number = Math.max(Math.min(((rgb >> 16) & 0xFF) + brite, 255), 0);
    var g:Number = Math.max(Math.min(((rgb >> 8) & 0xFF) + brite, 255), 0);
    var b:Number = Math.max(Math.min((rgb & 0xFF) + brite, 255), 0);

    return (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
} 

// there is an alternative method that accepts a value from -100 to 100
var color:Number = adjustBrightness(0xFF0000, brightness*100);

public static function adjustBrightness2(rgb:uint, brite:Number):uint
{
    var r:Number;
    var g:Number;
    var b:Number;

    if (brite == 0)
        return rgb;

    if (brite < 0)
    {
        brite = (100 + brite) / 100;
        r = ((rgb >> 16) & 0xFF) * brite;
        g = ((rgb >> 8) & 0xFF) * brite;
        b = (rgb & 0xFF) * brite;
    }
    else // bright > 0
    {
        brite /= 100;
        r = ((rgb >> 16) & 0xFF);
        g = ((rgb >> 8) & 0xFF);
        b = (rgb & 0xFF);

        r += ((0xFF - r) * brite);
        g += ((0xFF - g) * brite);
        b += ((0xFF - b) * brite);

        r = Math.min(r, 255);
        g = Math.min(g, 255);
        b = Math.min(b, 255);
    }

    return (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have a list of values from 0 to 1...

Let's assume this list is an array called `myList`. It has 100 values ranging from `0` to `1` (or 0.99).

To map length of 100 entries into the expected 255 (of Green and Blue, to get White) just divide:

```
(255/myList.length); //gives 2.55
2.55 * ( myList[i] * 100 ) //gives 0-255 range version (eg: myList[i]==0.5... now is 127)
```

First declare some variables...

```
public var temp_R :uint = 0;
public var temp_G :uint = 0;
public var temp_B :uint = 0;

public var RGB :uint = 0; //output colour (24-bit)
```

Then just update by using a For loop...

```
for (var j:uint = 0; j < myList.length; j++)
{
    //maximum 255 is divided by total values...
    //multiply by 100 to ramp up the List value... eg: If "myList[j]" == 0.5 then we want as == 50
    temp_Int = (255 / myList.length) * ( 100 * myList[j] ); 

    if( temp_Int > 255) { temp_Int = 255;} //clamp to 255 range

    temp_R = 255; //kept as constant value of 255
    temp_G = temp_B = temp_Int; //for whitening, these other two share same value

    RGB = (temp_R << 16) | (temp_G << 8) | temp_B; //generate output colour

    temp_BMD.setPixel(j, k, RGB );
}
```

Same logic within a *slighty* more compact For loop

```
for (var j:uint = 0; j < myList.length; j++)
{
    temp_Int = (255 / myList.length) * ( 100 * myList[j] );
    temp_R = 255; temp_G = temp_B = temp_Int; //set R to 255, set G and B to "temp_Int"
    RGB = (temp_R << 16) | (temp_G << 8) | temp_B; //generate output colour
    //temp_BMD.setPixel(j, 0, RGB ); //visual test on a Bitmap-Data object
}
```

Note: You can also "shrink" the peaking point by using `(255 / (myList.length / X) );` where `X` is a small value like 2, 4, or 8. Maybe it's helpful in some way for later projects.